# NFS client aggregates write requests even when application opens file with O_DSYNC

Tags: c, io, linux-kernel, nfs, nfsclient

I am running an application which opens a file in an NFS mount with `O_DSYNC` option. The application then writes `6500` bytes of data 1000 times to the file in a loop.

I monitored the client behavior and noticed that it was sending the writes to the underlying filesystem in batches of 4096 and 8192 bytes.

As per `man open`, Write operations on a file opened with `O_DSYNC` will complete according to the requirements of synchronized I/O data integrity completion. It further says that,

```
O_DSYNC provides synchronized I/O data integrity completion, meaning write operations will flush data to the underlying hardware, but will only flush metadata updates that are required to allow a subsequent read operation to complete successfully.
```

I assumed that with `O_DSYNC`, `write()` call will not return until the underlying filesystem has successfully written the data. That's not what's happening here. NFS client is caching writes and flushing them in multiples of 4k. Why is this so?

Note that, I am using an Amazon EC2 instance running Linux version 4.9, with a page size of 4096.

Comment: What behavior do you see on the older versions?

Comment: @AndrewHenle, When I simultaneously run a writer and a reader on 2 different machines, such that the writer sleeps for 4min after 500+ iterations of the loop. I note that application prints a log that it has written `6500xnumber_of_iterations` bytes, but the reader claims to be few bytes short. This is seen only on 4.9 and not on 4.1.

Comment: O_DSYNC only refers to file buffers in your process.  NFS has its own SYNC option for doing immediate writes vs. caching.  You also would have to set sync in the NFS export.

Comment: @stark, NFS mount is configured to write through, not use cache

Answer (score 0):

Device writes can only be multiples of the storage block size:  512 bytes for old disks or 4096 for many new disks.  Since files aren't aligned with disk blocks, this could cause a read-modify-write of two disk blocks resulting in an 8k write to the device, even though the file write is much smaller.